# Get the Opacity of a specific window

Tags: c++, .net, windows, winapi

How I can get the Opacity of a specifc window.
I have the window handle of other process, need to return Opacity.

Thanks!
Joseph

Comment: Do windows have a single opacity value? Where did you get the idea that this was a property that windows held?

Comment: Probably an XY problem. Not only is it a mistake to assume that the opacity is a fixed percentage, there's probably also an assumption that there is no distortion.

Comment: [GetLayeredWindowAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633508.aspx).

Comment: thanks @IInspectable